# Loop transformations with potentially shared objects

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
#include <vector>

int sum(const std::vector<int>& v) {
  int count = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    count += v[i];
  return count;
}
```

For the purposes of this question, assume that is the entire translation unit, that the implementation of `std::vector::size` and `std::vector::operator []` are both available to the compiler.

The compiler can trivially tell that `v` is not modified within the loop, since there are no function calls except those it has the source to.  So it is perfectly reasonable for the compiler to hoist the `size()` call outside the loop:

```
for(int i = 0, size = v.size(); i < size; ++i)
```

However, in a recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130975/gnu-compiler-optimization/8131093#8131093) it was suggested that, since `v` might be modified by another thread, the compiler is not allowed to perform that optimization.  It seems to me, however, that in such a case the function is already tragically broken, so limiting the compiler's options is rather pointless.  But I do not understand the new standard's rules regarding sequencing, and how they interact with expression reordering, so perhaps my intuition is wrong.

I am willing to assume that in C++03, that transformation is entirely valid, always.  But what of C++11?  Obviously, I could throw the function at a compiler and see what happens, but that's a lousy way to check conformance.

Answer (score 5):

As was said in one of the comments to the answer you linked, "the compiler doesn't care about other threads".  Unless you have an implementation of `std::vector` with explicit thread synchronisation constructs, this won't affect optimisation.

Comment: The comment in question was made by the fellow arguing that the compiler can't make the transformation.  So I end up with "the compiler doesn't care about other threads, but it has to be aware they exist" on one side, and "the compiler doesn't care about other threads, so it can pretend they don't exist on the other side."  I agree with your conclusion, but I'm still lacking the why.

Answer (score 2):

By looking only this piece of code, compilers does assume that `v` is *not* shared by other threads, and will perform inlining optimizations on `size()` and `operator[]`. There is no indication for compilers to judge this vector may be shared. Also, note that STL is not thread-safe.

If your concern is true (i.e., `v` might be modified by other threads), then the code itself would be wrong since `v[i]` may have data races. Then, you have to insert a proper critical section.

Comment: More correctly, the compiler can assume that `v` is not modified by other threads.  Multiple threads reading an object isn't a problem.

Comment: Of course, data races are defined one ore more current accesses while at least one access is write.

Comment: @James: But why can the compiler assume that?  Obviously it is not a safe assumption in general, so it either can't, or the standard gives it permission to somewhere.

Comment: @Dennis: If a compiler have to assume that a variable can be accessed by other threads, it's really too restrict condition for advanced optimizations. Of course, compilers are generally doing optimizations in very conservative way. But, I don't think multithreaded accesses are not common case. So, it's reasonable for compilers to assume that a variable does not have data races and no current accesses. That's why compilers have `volatile` keyword for your concern. To sum, it's a reasonable trade-off.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose Because that's the way threading is defined.  It's up to the programmer to define the granularity, not the compiler.  It really can't be otherwise: what should the granularity be here?  It has to be the entire loop, since otherwise, another thread could pop elements off the vector between `i < v.size()` and the access `v[i]`.  And trying to manage atomicity at this level would be extremely expensive (since it would require a compiler generated mutex) and often not needed.

Comment: @DennisZickefoose With regards to the standard: C++03 doesn't address threading; as far as C++03 is concerned, accessing anything from more than one thread is undefined behavior.  If you're running in a multithreaded environment, you're depending on other standards (e.g. Posix) as well.  C++11 does introduce threading, adopting basically the Posix rules.  Which are: if an object (memory location) may be modified in any thread, then all accesses to it must be synchronized (explicitly by the programmer).  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_09.html

Answer (score 1):

In C++03, thread is a library concept not a language concept. Therefore, it is not a requirement for the compiler to care about threads.

Comment: If the only standard were C++03, that would be true.  Posix imposes some additional constraints, and compilers under Unix machines are expected to be Posix compliant, as well as C++ compliant.  A similar situation exists in all environments: compilers are bound by a number of specifications: one or more standards, OS specifications, its own specifications, etc.  C++ compilers do "care about threads", at least in environments which support multi-threading.  (This has not always been the case, and I can remember when g++ used static variables in its exception handling).